# Would it have been possible to trap Lord Voldemort in Professor Quirrell's body?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Had Harry had not interfered with Professor Quirrell/Lord Voldemort when they go into the final room with the Mirror of Erised, Dumbledore and Snape could have easily cornered and trapped them during their exit, or maybe in the room itself. In this case, maybe Quirrell and Voldemort would not have gotten the Philosopher's Stone.

If Dumbledore and Snape could have captured them alive, they could have jailed them or put them in a secluded room from which escape was impossible. They could have kept Voldemort alive with small doses of Unicorn blood, small enough amounts that Voldemort wouldn't die, but also wouldn't have the energy to do magic.

Thus, the whole set of problems that occur further along in the story would have been easily averted.

Would this have been possible in any way?

(If this would have happened, maybe the Death Eaters would have hijacked the Hogwarts Express and demanded the release of Voldemort.)

Comment: I think answers to this question will be purely speculative. There is probably no canon answer to this.

Comment: @LarsEbert: I know, but just imagining possibilities.

Comment: @LarsEbert - Quality speculative questions and answers are okay at SE, if I recall correctly. I think it's in the FAQ. A speculative answer grounded in canon wouldn't bother me, but I realize it's a YMMV thing. :)

Comment: The interesting thing is: Voldemort was freely able to exit all of the traps..

Comment: Voldemort posessed Quirrell after he (Q) botched the retrieval of the PS. I always assumed he could posess or disposess anyone at will, he fled because the host body was dead (or dying), sure, but I believe he could have left any time he chose to. Which would have left the interesting question, what that would have done to a still alive Quirrell... After all Voldemort can still possess others even after he regained his body (like he tried with Harry in the Ministry Atrium, who could have been a special case similar to Nagino because of the Horcrux thing, though)...

Comment: [Lack of a canon answer is not a valid close reason](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3014/5184)

Comment: Just something I noticed in your question - "They could have kept Voldemort alive with small doses of Unicorn blood..." They wouldn't need to, as Voldemort had his Horcruxes to keep him alive.(If you want to call that being alive :/ )

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/are-questions-without-enough-data-unanswerable https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/should-all-questions-without-explicit-canon-answers-be-closed https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11273/what-do-we-do-with-this-question-that-doesnt-have-a-current-answer https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11329/are-answers-that-state-we-dont-know-acceptable

Comment: [Meta post about this question.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12584/answer-based-reopen-request)

Comment: @Alex Response to your meta was mixed, but this seems to be an on-topic question about HP lore, and 9 different people have voted to reopen it at various times. I've just become the 10th.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I'm joining the Hogwarts .... errr reopening express. Whoever voted to close this is doing so in error considering the scope policy on SFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer would be no. This would not be possible.

Voldemort is evidently the most powerful dark wizard in the world. When he ruled, there was fear amongst everyone, terror across the world.

> Every week, news comes of more deaths, more disappearances, more torturing ... The Ministry of Magic’s in disarray, they don’t know what to do, they’re trying to keep everything hidden from the Muggles, but meanwhile, Muggles are dying too. **Terror everywhere ... panic ... confusion ... that’s how it used to be.** *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

Severus against Voldemort, he doesn't stand a chance. Dumbledore on the other hand, is the only wizard that Voldemort ever feared. Dumbledore could have dueled for an exceptionally long time, but remember what Dumbledore said himself?

> "You flatter me," said Dumbledore calmly. "**Voldemort had powers I will never have**."

This said, Voldemort may not be the better wizard, but in fact have *Dark Magic* that Dumbledore wouldn't dare to use. Using this magic may have made their powers on par. Even then, Voldemort was still weak at that time.

> I have strength enough for this.

Voldemort in *Philosophers Stone*.

As to an inescapable room, I highly doubt that would be possible. Azkaban has had many breakouts, but is still probably one of the best and secure jails. The most the Ministry would possibly do is to make a new "jail", specifically for Voldemort, due to his past.

You could keep giving Quirrell food, but as per spookypeanut answer, I believe that Voldemort would possess Quirrell not to eat it. If Quirrell dies, Voldemort would transform into a misty, ghost like substance, and escape would be easier.

You also said, "the whole set of problems that occur further along in the story would have been easily averted." Out of universe, the whole entire series revolves around Harry and Voldemort. Even if he was captured, there would be no story whatsoever.

Also, remember this is *Voldemort* that we are talking about. It may be Quirrell's body, but he had the Wrath of Voldemort behind him this entire time. To try to bring Voldemort to justice, to a jail cell, is the equivalent of Earth shifting it's course away from the sun.

Answer (score 2):

While not specifying exactly what could be done to Voldemort in his spirit form, there are at least two passages that indicate that *something* could have been done against him. In Chapter Thirty-Three of *Goblet of Fire* Voldemort tells the Death Eaters the following:

> "Only one power remained to me. I could possess the bodies of others. But I dared not go where other humans were plentiful, for I knew that the Aurors were still abroad and searching for me.

If there was no way that spirit-Voldemort could be captured, or otherwise defeated, there would be little reason for him to be afraid of hanging out where the Aurors were around.

Similarly, in Chapter Two of *Half-Blood Prince* Snape says the following to Bellatrix:

> He was in a pitiable condition, very weak, sharing the body of a mediocre wizard. He did not dare reveal himself to a former ally if that ally might turn him over to Dumbledore or the Ministry.

Again, this would indicate that there would be some way for Dumbledore or the Ministry to "secure" Voldemort, despite him being incorporeal at the time.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It's a perfectly valid answer with good reasoning from canon source

Answer (score 0):

Given how weak-minded Quirrell is, I would suggest that it would have been easy for Voldemort to persuade his body to die. Also, there's nothing to suggest that if Voldemort has been brought back (as in at the end of GoF), that he wouldn't disappear from Quirrell. So while it may have been possible to keep him contained, I would speculate that nothing would have been gained by it: anything that would bring him back to life would still work.